# How to decouple a system of ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I understand the basic idea of this and finding a similar matrix, but I am hoping to see an example of it all being tied together.

How would I decouple the system:

$$\dot{x} = 3y - 4x$$
$$\dot{y} = 5y - 6x$$

Answer (score 5):

You can write your system using matrices and vectors as

$$\frac d{dt}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}3 &-4\\5&-6\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$$

Now you consider the Jordan decomposition (Jordan normal form) of that matrix
$$ \begin{bmatrix}3 &-4\\5&-6\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-1 &1\\5&-4\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}-2 &0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}-1 &1\\5&-4\end{bmatrix}.$$

You can now multiply your differential equation with the transformation matrix from left to get

\begin{align*}
\frac d{dt}\begin{bmatrix}-1 &1\\5&-4\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} & = \begin{bmatrix}-2 &0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}-1 &1\\5&-4\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} \\
\frac d{dt}\begin{bmatrix}-x + y\\5x -4y \end{bmatrix} & = \begin{bmatrix}-2 &0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-x + y\\5x -4y \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Note that we can pull the constant matrix into the differentiation.
Now we see we have to substitute $v = -x+y$ and $w=5x - 4y$ and obtain the decoupled system
\begin{align*}
\dot v = -2 v, \\
\dot w = -w.
\end{align*}

Note that this only works when your coefficient matrix is diagonalizable (over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$). Otherwise some of the components are still coupled.

Comment: Hey, thank you. How did you formulate your Jacobi decomposition? That is the bit I always struggle to 'come up with'

Comment: How to do a Jacobi decomposition is another question. I'm sure you'll find something. But as for me, I almost always use computer algebra software to find it. You could even use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Jordan+decomposition+of+%7B%7B3,-4%7D,%7B5,-6%7D%7D).

Comment: Changed. Thank you, eagle eye :)

Comment: Are you sure that this is Jacobi decomposition? I bet it's Jordan normal form :)

Comment: O god! I beg for forgiveness!! Of course you are right @Evgeny! I always mix the names Jacobi and Jordan up. You don't know how often I talk about the "Jordanian" or the "Jacobi decomposition". Changed and thank you!

Comment: @Wauzl Heh, that's alright, we all do typos from time to time :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I should say that I'm not quite sure what you mean by decoupling, but here is what I would do: subtract the equations.
$$\dot{y}-\dot{x} = 2y-2x$$
Now we can set $u$ = y-x, and we have
$$\dot{u}=2u$$
Solving this gives us
$$u=ke^{2x}$$
Then we can plug this back in to our original equations to get:
$$\dot{x} = 3ke^{2t} - x$$
and 
$$\dot{y} = 6ke^{2t} - y$$
I would consider these equations now decoupled. I hope this helps!

Comment: Decoupling would be what you just did. But we are always told to do it by finding eigenvectors, eigenvalue and then do a coordinate transformation. Any ideas on how to do it that way?

Comment: A coordinate transformation is what I did with the $u=y-x$. I guess this is the algebra behind the linear algebra. As for deriving the coordinate transform, note that if there is a difference between the coefficients of x and y in both differential equations, then you can scale one of them by a certain factor to make the differences the same, then add or subtract them.

Comment: You can see from the last two equations that with $v=y-2x$ you get the equation $\dot v=-v$, so that you have a complete coordinate transformation.

Comment: I see! Thanks @LutzL. My method did seem a bit unclean.

Comment: Every method is good that leads to a solution in an easily verifiable way. Finding an approach by intense staring at the problem just does not always work.

Comment: You might be interested to look at the frequency domain via a Fourier transform. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4675119/are-bifurcations-preserved-under-fourier-transforms) for a general nonlinear system.